# Inverse of the Pascal Matrix

Tags: matrices, polynomials, binomial-coefficients

Let $P_n$ be the $(n+1) \times (n+1)$ matrix that contains the numbers of Pascal's triangle in the upper triangle. For example in the case of $n=3$
$$
P_3 = 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 3 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
or in general 
$$
(P_n)_{ij} = \binom{j}{i} \lfloor  i \leq j  \rceil  ~~~\text{for}~~ i,j \in \{0,...,n \} 
$$
using the definition
$$
\lfloor  A  \rceil :=
\begin{cases}
    1 & \text{A is true} \\
    0 & \text{A is not true}
    \end{cases}
$$
This matrix is invertible since $\det P_n = 1$.
For smaller cases like $n=3$, I calulated the inverse of the matrix by hand and found
$$
P_3^{-1} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & -1 & 1 & -1 \\
0 & 1 & -2 & 3 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & -3 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
$n=2,4$ led to similar results, so I'm guessing that the inverse should be
$$
(P_n^{-1})_{ij} = (-1)^{j+i}(P_n)_{ij} = (-1)^{j+i} \binom{j}{i} \lfloor  i \leq j  \rceil
$$
But I have not been able to prove or disprove this yet. So far I tried multiplying the two matirces which gives
$$
\sum^j_{k=i} (-1)^{j+k} \binom{j}{k} \binom{k}{i} = \delta_{ij}
$$
if one asumes that the result is the unit matrix. For $i=0$ and $j>0$ this gives
$$
\delta_{0j} = 0 
= \sum^j_{k=0} (-1)^{j+k} \binom{j}{k} \binom{k}{0}
= \sum^j_{k=0} (-1)^{k} \binom{j}{k}
$$
which is an identity I know to be true, so it reasures me a little bit that the above should also be true.

Comment: Instead of proving the above mentioned formula for all $(j,i)$ you can also use induction and prove it only for $(n,i)$, maybe it is easier. The $(j,n)$ entries are easy to handle

Comment: Use $\binom jk \binom ki = \binom ji \binom {j-i}{k-i}$.

Comment: [Binomial transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_transform)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In my opinion this is a bit simpler to prove, if we interpret the matrix $P_n$ as a linear transformation.

Consider the space $V_n$ of polynomials of degree $\le n$ (over, say $\Bbb{Q}$, but you are welcome to use reals or complex numbers, or any other field actually).

The mapping $T: f(x)\mapsto f(x+1)$ for all $f(x)\in V_n$ is obviously linear. My key point is to observe that $P_n$ is the matrix $M_{\mathcal B}(T)$ of $T$ with respect to the obvious basis $\mathcal{B}=\{1,x,x^2,\ldots,x^n\}$ of $V_n$. This is because for any $k, 0\le k\le n$ the binomial formula says that
$$T(x^k)=\sum_{\ell=0}^k\binom k\ell x^\ell.$$
From this we can read the coordinates of $T(x^k)$ with respect to $\mathcal{B}$, and see that those coincide the $k$th column of $P_n$ (numbered from $0$ to $n$). That's exactly what the claim was.

It is obvious that the inverse of $T$ is given by the recipe
$
T^{-1}:f(x)\mapsto f(x-1).
$
A similar application of the binomial formula shows that the matrix 
$M_{\mathcal B}(T^{-1})$ then is exactly your prescribed inverse of $P_n$ containing binomial coefficients - this time with alternating signs.

But, by basic linear algebra
$$
M_{\mathcal B}(T^{-1})=M_{\mathcal B}(T)^{-1}.
$$

Comment: Nice solution! I especially like that it does not require to guess the form of the inverse. It is also very close to the reason I got confronted with the problem in the first place. Because I was looking at the change of base from $\{x^j\}$ to $\{(x+1)^j\}$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen This is brilliant, really, a pity that I can only give (+1). I just wanted to know the formula for the inverse of the Pascal matrix and searched the web for it. Now I found not only the formula, but this higher level view on it which makes everything so clear. It feels similar to the moment when I was told that the addition theorems for sin and cos are just real and imaginary parts of the power rule for the complex exponential function.

Answer (score 9):

By the suggestion of [Sungjin Kim](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/67070/i707107) one can use
\begin{equation}
\binom{j}{k}\binom{k}{i} = \binom{j}{i}\binom{j-i}{k-i}
\end{equation}
which is useful since it leads to the sum only going over one of the binomial coefficients. It leads to
\begin{align}
\sum^j_{k=i} (-1)^{j+k} \binom{j}{k} \binom{k}{i}
&= \sum^j_{k=i} (-1)^{j+k} \binom{j}{i}\binom{j-i}{k-i} \\
&=  (-1)^j \binom{j}{i} \sum^j_{k=i} (-1)^{k} \binom{j-i}{k-i} \\
&= (-1)^{j} \binom{j}{i} \sum^{j-i}_{k=0} (-1)^{k+i} \binom{j-i}{k} \\
&= (-1)^{j+i} \binom{j}{i} (1 - 1)^{j-i} = \delta_{ij}
\end{align}
The identity used is easily proven by
$$
\binom{j}{k}\binom{k}{i} 
= \frac{j!}{k!(j-k)!} \frac{k!}{i!(k-i)!}
= \frac{j!}{i!(j-i)!} \frac{(j-i)!}{(j-k)!(k-i)!}
= \binom{j}{i}\binom{j-i}{k-i}
$$
Another way of showing the identity involving $\delta_{ij}$ is to start with $x^j$ and using the binomial thoerem twice
$$
x^j = (x+0)^j = ((x+1) - 1 )^j = ~...~ 
= \sum^j_{i=0} \sum^j_{k=i} (-1)^{j+k} \binom{j}{k} \binom{k}{i} x^i
$$
comparing coefficients of the two sides of the equation, then also leads to the desired result. You can find the whole calcultion [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1866113/351999), along whith other examples of [when adding 0 really counts](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1684421/when-adding-zero-really-counts/1866113#1866113).

Answer (score 4):

In the following it's somewhat more convenient to equivalently consider the *transpose* $P_n^T$ of the matrix $P_n$ and its inverse.

We obtain for $n=3$

\begin{align*}
P_3^T&=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 &  & & \\
1 & 1 & & \\
1 & 2 & 1 & \\
1 & 3 & 3 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}=\left(\binom{i}{j}\right)_{0\leq i,j\leq 3}
\\
\left(P_3^T\right)^{-1}&=
\begin{pmatrix}
\begin{array}{rrrr}
1 &  &  & \\
-1 & 1 & & \\
1 & -2 & 1 & \\
-1 & 3 & 3 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\end{pmatrix}=\left((-1)^{i+j}\binom{i}{j}\right)_{0\leq i,j\leq 3}
\end{align*}

> The elements of the Pascal matrix can be considered as coefficients of *binomial inverse pairs*. These are sequences
>   $(a_i)_{0\leq     i \leq n},(b_i)_{0\leq i\leq  n}$ which are related for $n\geq 0$ via
>   \begin{align*}
> a_n=\sum_{i=0}^n\binom{n}{i}b_i\qquad\text{resp.}\qquad b_n=\sum_{i=0}^n(-1)^{i+n}\binom{n}{i}a_i\tag{1}
> \end{align*}

One relation implies the other in (1). This can be seen  via *[exponential generating functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function#Exponential_generating_function)*.

Let $A(x)$ and $B(x)$ be two exponential generating functions

$$A(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_{n}\frac{x^n}{n!} \qquad\qquad\text{ and }\qquad\qquad  B(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty b_{n}\frac{x^n}{n!}$$

The  expressions in (1) are the coefficients of

\begin{align*}
A(x)=B(x)e^x\qquad\qquad\text{resp.}\qquad\qquad B(x)=A(x)e^{-x}\tag{2}
\end{align*}
The relationship in (2) is obvious and so the relationship in (1) follows.

> The most important characterization of the pair of inverse relation in (1) is the *orthogonal relation* the pair    implies.  This  follows
>   by  substituting one of the pair into the other. We obtain for $n\geq 0$
>
> \begin{align*}
> a_n&=\sum_{j=0}^n\binom{n}{j}b_j\\
> &=\sum_{j=0}^n\binom{n}{j}\sum_{i=0}^j(-1)^{i+j}\binom{j}{i}a_i\\
> &=\sum_{i=0}^n a_i\sum_{j=i}^n(-1)^{i+j}\binom{n}{j}\binom{j}{i}
> \end{align*}
>   Hence the orthogonal relation is
>   \begin{align*}
> \delta_{ni}=\sum_{j=i}^n(-1)^{i+j}\binom{n}{j}\binom{j}{i}
> \end{align*}
>   with $\delta_{ni}$ the *[Kronecker Delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta)*.

Answer (score 1):

The inverse of $P_n$ also follows from a familiar representation of $GL(2,\mathbb{R})$. Let $\{u,v\}$ be a basis of $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $S^n(\mathbb{R}^2)$ denote the vector space of homogeneous polynomials of degree $n$ in the variables $u$ and $v$. Then, any $A\in GL(2,\mathbb{R})$ acts linearly on $p(u,v)\in S^n(\mathbb{R}^2)$ by $A\cdot p(u,v)=p(Au,Av).$ Choose $\{u^{n-j}v^j\}_{j=0}^n$ as a basis of $S^n(\mathbb{R}^2)$. Then, the given group action induces a homomorphism $\varphi_n: GL(2,\mathbb{C})\to GL(n+1,\mathbb{C})$ defined by
$$\begin{pmatrix}a & b\\ c & d\end{pmatrix}\mapsto \left([t^i](a+ct)^{n-j}(b+dt)^j\right)_{i,j=0}^n$$
where $[t^i]f(t)$ denotes the coefficient of $t^i$ in $f(t)$. Let $M=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1\\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}.$ Then, we see that $P_n=\varphi_n(M).$ Since $\varphi_n$ is a homomorphism, we get $P_n^{-1}=\varphi_n(M^{-1})$. But $M^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix}1 & -1\\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$. Hence, by definition of $\varphi_n$, we obtain explicit indices as you described.

Answer (score 1):

With Jyrki's idea, the map of $V_n$
$$T_{\lambda} f(t) \mapsto f(t+\lambda)$$
satisfies
$$T_{\lambda} (t^k) = (t+\lambda)^k = \sum_{l=0}^k \binom{k}{l} \lambda^{k-l} t^l$$
so the matrix of $T_{\lambda}$ is
$$M_{\lambda}=( \lambda^{k-l} \binom{k}{l} )_{0
\le l, k\le n}$$

Note that
$$T_{\lambda} \circ T_{\mu} = T_{\lambda + \mu}\\
T_{-\lambda} = T_{\lambda}^{-1}$$
so
$$M_{\lambda} \cdot M_{\mu} = M_{\lambda + \mu}\\
 M_{-\lambda} = M_{\lambda}^{-1}$$

Taylor's formula for polynomials tells us  that

$$T_{\lambda} = \exp ( \lambda D)$$

where $D$ is the derivative map.  At the level of matrices we get therefore

$$M_{\lambda} = \exp ( \lambda  N)$$

where $N=(n_{ij})$ is the nilpotent matrix with $n_{i, i+1} = i+1$, for $i=0, 1, \ldots, n-1$, and $0$ otherwise.