# Non-crossing partitions without singletons

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations, combinatorial-proofs, catalan-numbers

A partition of $[n]$ is non-crossing if whenever four distinct elements $1\le a < b < c < d \le n $ are s.t.
$a, c$ are both in one block and $b, d$ are both in another one, then the two blocks coincide.

I have showed that the number of non-crossing partitions (by dividing when $k$ and $n+1$ are connected and when they are disjointed) is:

$$
f(n+1) = \sum_{k=1}^{n+1} f(k-1)f(n+1-k)
$$

Which is the recurrence formula for the Catalan's numbers as $f(0) = 1 = C_0$.

How to find a recurrence for the number of non-crossing partitions of $[n]$ without singletons? I have not found a good line of reasoning yet.

Comment: Your definition isn't easy to understand as it is. First of all, the word "block" isn't appropriate (a partition of a set is a set of covering **subsets** with no common elements, these subsets being often called "equivalence **classes**"). Moreover, can you give one or two **examples**...

Comment: @JeanMarie There was a typo in the definition I wrote, so I fixed it, hope it's clear now

Comment: No more clear. It must be the same for other colleagues, explaining that you haven't had echoes to your question. **Please give an example**. For example, how many "blocks" do you have ? As many as you want or only 2 ?

Comment: If $n=7$, can $\{ \{3,5,7\},\{2,4\},\{1,6\} \}$ be called "non-crossing" without "singlets" (single element class= singleton) ? Please answer.

Comment: @JeanMarie yes exactly I meant without singletons, another way to visualize them is illustrated here https://robertdickau.com/noncrossingpartitions.html, for example. You can think about $[n]$ as the set $\{1, 2, \dots , n \}$ and about the classes as blocks of a partition of that set which satisfy the conditions.

Comment: Interesting reference. A possible way of attack: let g(n) be the count. Compute (by hand, by computer ?) the first values $g(2)=1, g(3)=1,g(4)=3, g(6)=5...$ (not sure), and then submit it to OEIS site. I have more than once found this type of query rewarding.

Comment: Have a look at T(n,k) as defined in https://oeis.org/A091867 (with $k=0$)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Count the number $f(n)$ by cases of how many singletons the partition has. Let's denote by $g(n)$ the number of noncrossing partitions of $[n]$ without singletons. We have

$$f(n) = \sum_{j=0}^n {n \choose j}g(n-j)$$

because we can choose the $j$ singletons out of $n$ numbers and then the rest forms a non-crossing partition of $[n-j]$ without singletons.

We can express this as a matrix equation $f = Ag$ where $A = [{i \choose j}]_{ij}$.

Now (see [for example here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1852826/inverse-of-the-pascal-matrix))

$$A^{-1} = [(-1)^{i+j}{i \choose j}]_{ij}$$

So we have a formula for the vector $g$ (since we know $f(n)=\frac{1}{n+1} { {2n} \choose n}$ are the Catalan numbers):

$$g(n) = \sum_{j=0}^n \frac{(-1)^{n+j}}{j+1} { {n} \choose j} { {2j} \choose j}. $$

**EDIT:**
These are [the Riordan numbers](https://oeis.org/A005043) (a [more general OEIS-sequence](https://oeis.org/A091867) was already linked by Jean Marie)

In the paper: [link](http://users.dimi.uniud.it/%7Egiacomo.dellariccia/Glossary/Motzkin/Bernhart1999.pdf) the following generating function equation is given and used to derive a recursion.

If we put $y = \sum g(n)x^n$, then

$$y = \frac{1}{1+x} + xy^2.$$

Implicit differentiation and arduous algebraic manipulation of the equations leads to

$$1 - x(1+x)(1-3x)y' = (1-3x^2)y.$$

From this the recursion

$$g(n) = \frac{n-1}{n+1}\left(2g(n-1)+3g(n-2)\right)$$

can be read.

Comment: That's really useful, thank you so much! Do you have any idea how to formulate a recursion for the $g(n)$?

Comment: There's a nice recursion given in OEIS and a multitude of characterizations of the sequence. I put the main steps from one of the references into the solution. But I didn't check the derivation of the linear differential equation. Perhaps it can be verified by solving the generating equation for $y$ in terms of $x$.