# How to evaluate $1 - \frac{\binom{n^2}{1}}{\binom{n+1}{1}} + \frac{\binom{n^2}{2}}{\binom{n+2}{2}} - \frac{\binom{n^2}{3}}{\binom{n+3}{3}} + ..$

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

How to evaluate $1 - \frac{\binom{n^2}{1}}{\binom{n+1}{1}} + \frac{\binom{n^2}{2}}{\binom{n+2}{2} } - \frac{\binom{n^2}{3}}{\binom{n+3}{3}} + \frac{\binom{n^2}{4}}{\binom{n+4}{4}} - ......$

I really have no idea how to proceed in this question. Expanding it by the formula isn't helping as much as I can see. And the options are extremely sofisticated as well like 1/n, 1/(n+1), 1. How to proceed?

Comment: Why do you think it should have a closed form simplification?

Comment: Mainly because of the options. The options are 1/n , 1/(n+1), 1 and none of these. I know it can be none of these, but the options make me think the it will be transformed into closed form. I was thinking of trying to expand it using the formula and try to make a difference of series or something but wasn't able to.

Comment: Is the sum really infinite? Because if it is as the question seems to show, then in the numerator, when the number of terms gets large enough, eventually the $k$ term in ${n^2 \choose k}$ will be larger than $n^2$, which would create a problem.

Comment: No problem: those terms are all zero.

Comment: Is it $\lim_{n\to\infty}$ ?

Comment: Which book/problem set is this from?

Comment: Actually I am an amateur teacher. A senior teacher from my academy gave a problem sheet in the top batch, and one of the students from that batch asked me this. So, don't know the exact source.

Comment: Giving a law of small numbers answer... the first two terms are $\frac 12,\frac 13$...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> A variation. We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{j=0}^{n^2}}&\color{blue}{(-1)^j\binom{n^2}{j}\binom{n+j}{j}^{-1}}\\
> &=\sum_{j=0}^{n^2}\binom{n^2}{j}\binom{-n-1}{j}^{-1}\tag{1}\\
> &=\sum_{j=0}^{n^2}\binom{n^2}{j}(-n)\int_{0}^1t^j(1-t)^{-n-1-j}\,dt\tag{2}\\
> &=(-n)\int_{0}^1(1-t)^{-n-1}\sum_{j=0}^{n^2}\binom{n^2}{j}\left(\frac{t}{1-t}\right)^j\,dt\\
> &=(-n)\int_{0}^1(1-t)^{-n-1}\left(1+\frac{t}{1-t}\right)^{n^2}\,dt\\
> &=(-n)\int_{0}^1(1-t)^{-n^2-n-1}\,dt\\
> &=\frac{-n}{-n^2-n}\\
> &\color{blue}{=\frac{1}{n+1}}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we use the binomial identity $\binom{-p}{q}=\binom{p+q-1}{q}(-1)^q$.
- In (2) we apply the identity $\binom{n}{r}^{-1}=(n+1)\int_{0}^1t^r(1-t)^{n-r}\,dt$.

Comment: @MathLover: Thanks, MathLover. :-)

Comment: Hey, just can you give me links with proofs of those comments? I will really appreciate that. The 2nd one seems provable using a trigonometric substitution, but the first one seems awkward and it's the first time I have seen anything like that.

Comment: @Avinash Bhawnani : if you replace the binomial coefficients with the explicit formula $\binom{\alpha}{k} = \frac{\alpha(\alpha-1)\cdot\cdot\cdot (\alpha-k+1)}{k!}$, (1) can easily be obtained. On the other hand, I don't know if you'll manage to prove the second one with a mere trigo substitution (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Relationship_between_gamma_function_and_beta_function for a proof involving double integrals, and see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3528/beta-function-derivation/3540#3540 for a proof involving intuition)

Comment: Thank you so much. I actually didn't try, but just had a feeling that with trigo substis I will be able to get it. Obviously, I was far from it.

Comment: @charMD: Thanks for the nice references.

Answer (score 6):

Below is a quite brutal approach : whenever I see inverses of binomial coefficients, I try to use the following relation between the Gamma and Beta functions (I can provide a link if needed) :

> $$\mbox{With  } 0 < m \le n,\quad \quad \ \frac{1}{\binom{m+n}{m}} = \frac{mn}{m+n} \cdot \displaystyle{\int_0^1} t^{m-1}(1-t)^{n-1} dt$$

Your sum becomes :

$$S_n = 1 + \sum \limits_{k=1}^{n^2} (-1)^k \binom{n^2}{k} \frac{kn}{k+n} \displaystyle{\int_0^1} t^{k-1}(1-t)^{n-1} dt$$

$$S_n = 1 + n \displaystyle{\int_0^1} (1-t)^{n-1} \cdot \Big( \sum \limits_{k=1}^{n^2} \frac{(-1)^k k}{k+n} \binom{n^2}{k} t^{k-1} \Big) dt$$

*Short interlude :* we can simplify this sum. Denote $f : t \mapsto t^{n+1} \sum \limits_{k=1}^{n^2} \frac{(-1)^k k}{k+n} \binom{n^2}{k} t^{k-1}$. Then $f'(t) = \sum \limits_{k=1}^{n^2} (-1)^k k \binom{n^2}{k} t^{k+n-1} = t^n \frac{d}{dt} \big( \sum \limits_{k=0}^{n^2} \binom{n^2}{k} (-t)^k \Big) = t^n \frac{d}{dt} \Big( (1-t)^{n^2} \Big) = -n^2 t^n (1-t)^{n^2-1}$.

Hence $$S_n = 1 + n \displaystyle{\int_0^1} (1-t)^{n-1} \cdot \frac{1}{t^{n+1}} \displaystyle{\int_0^{t}}-n^2 s^n (1-s)^{n^2-1} ds dt$$

and by exchanging the integrals : 
$$S_n = 1 - n^3 \displaystyle{\int_0^1} s^n (1-s)^{n^2-1} \cdot \displaystyle{\int_s^1} \frac{(1-t)^{n-1}}{t^{n+1}} dtds$$

$$S_n = 1 - n^3 \displaystyle{\int_0^1} s^n (1-s)^{n^2-1} \cdot \frac{(1-s)^n}{n s^n}ds$$

$$S_n = 1 -n^2 \displaystyle{\int_0^1} (1-s)^{n^2+n-1} = 1 - \frac{n^2}{n^2+n}$$

There might (*must*) be a more elegant way, but with this we can conclude that $S_n = \frac{1}{n+1}$.

Comment: I've been trying hard to get to the answer without using the gamma or beta function. Is there anyway it can be simplified from here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zUNrV.jpg ?

Comment: Thanks ! And btw @Rick, to conclude with your method, it boils down to $\sum \limits_{k=0}^{n-1} (-1)^k \binom{n^2+n}{k} = \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n+1} \binom{n^2+n}{n}$. Wolfram says this is true, but I don't know how it does. In any case, there are more chances to prove this with some counting argument

Comment: alright, let me know if you get a proof for that last step :)

Comment: @Rick: A proof can be found at *[this MSE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1684421/when-adding-zero-really-counts/2589311#2589311)*. In fact a clever multiplication with $\pm 1$ does the job.

Comment: @Markus Scheuer Great, thank you !

Comment: @charMD: You're welcome, thanks.